# What's wrong with this XPath query?

Tags: php, xpath, curl

I want to make headers list from this url: http://www.2dplay.com/action-games.htm

My query is as given:

```
 $gamelist = $xpath->query('//div[@id="wrapper"]//div[@id="body_wrap"]//div[@id="content"]//
table[@id="cat_games"]//tbody//tr//td//h2//a');
    foreach($gamelist as $e){
        echo $e->nodeValue;
        echo "<br/>";
    }
```

It gives no results. If I close the query to table[@id="cat_games"] it gives every txt information in one node. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the reason that you put `//` everywhere? And secondly, are you sure that there is a `<tbody>` element in the website's source?

Comment: yes there is <tbody> because I'm using google chrome's inspect element and as I said the problem shouldn't be in the // cause with smaller query for the same url it works but not in the required way

Comment: Check the source, not inspect. Chrome may add the tbody tag on its own (firefox does), even if it's not in the source.

Comment: Thank all of you. Chrome adds the <tbody> tag itself

Comment: Reg. `//` - can you please try for the query that works with `////` instead? I'm curious if that works. And for the source: I meant the file source, not what the browser shows when you inspect the document that has been already loaded into the browser and therefore modified by the browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must know that the `id` attribute for an element must be unique, according to [W3C XHTML 1.0 C.8 section](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#C_8). XHTML 1.0 is a *reformulation of HTML 4 in XML 1.0*, therefore the [HTML4 7.5.2 definition](http://www.w3.org/TR/html40/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2) applies here too.

Since the document you are parsing is declared as XHTML 1.0, you do not need to provide the full path to the element you want because the `table` element has an `id` attribute. You can resolve this element directly instead:

```
//table[@id="cat_games"]/tr/td/h2/a
```

If you fear the structure of the table may change (i.e.: a `<tbody>` tag may be added eventually), you can also make a more generic query:

```
//table[@id="cat_games"]//h2/a
```